# RuntimeException when patch submission. Module Webform Rest

Tags: webforms, http-request

When i send a PATCH request to my site to /webform_rest/{webform_id}/submission/{sid}?_format=json with the body

```
{
    "data":{
        "sincronizado":1
    }
}
```

or

```
{
  "sincronizado":1
}
```

from postman, I receive a 500 error.

The site log displays the next error:

> RuntimeException: Callable
> "Drupal\webform_rest\Plugin\rest\resource\WebformSubmissionResource::patch"
> requires a value for the "$webform_data" argument. en
> Drupal\Component\Utility\ArgumentsResolver->handleUnresolvedArgument()
> (line 142 of
> /usr/home/example.com/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/ArgumentsResolver.php).

Am I making a bad request? What is the `$webform_data` argument? My webform has a field "sincronizado", of type value.

I'm using Drupal 9.
REST UI 8.x-1.18.
RESTful Web Services 9.0.2
Webform 6.0.0-alpha12
Webform Rest 4.0.0-beta1

---

Same problem sending sid parameter with Webform rest version 8.x-2.0-beta3.

My request from postman, in curl code is

`curl --location --request PATCH 'http://example.com/webform_rest/webform-id-example/submission/36?_format=json' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic (admin user and password in base 64)' \
--data-raw '{  
"sincronizado":"1"
}'`

Answer (score 0):

Ok mate if you open up
webform_rest\Plugin\rest\resource\WebformSubmissionResource.php

and find the patch method you will see

```
public function patch($webform_id, $uuid, array $webform_data) { ...
```

looks like Webform Rest 4.0.0-beta1 is now using the submission uuid
so

```
/webform_rest/{webform_id}/submission/{sid}
```

"sid" should now be Webform Submission UUID

for the body field or the $webform_data

the module is looking for

```
  foreach ($webform_data as $field => $value) {
      $webform_submission->setElementData($field, $value);
    }
```

so your json should look like:

```
   {
    "filed_name": "value"
   }
```

because json_decode($json_string, true) will return an array.

if that does not work then file a bug ticket

Comment: Thanks. I had seen the uuid parameter in the patch function. I've tested with uuid and with `{ "sincronizado":1}` and `{ "sincronizado":"1"}`, but ever with same result. The problem is that the patch function is not receiving the `$webform_data` parameter. If i set a default value [] for `$webform_data` parameter in patch function on WebformSubmissionResource.php i get the response 200 with message >{
> "error": {
> "message": "No data has been submitted."
> }
>} I've sent and issue on the module project page: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rest/issues/3166084